# select points outside the cells in a lattice?

Tags: functions, regions, computational-geometry

I am creating a honey comb lattice with cells wherein the cells are some distance apart. please see the figure below.

[image]

I am using the following lines of code to generate this lattice:

```
(* initial pts of the cell *)
pts1 = ArrayFlatten[{{N@CirclePoints[6], 0}}];
pts2 = Quiet@Distribute[{{0, 0, 1}} + pts1, List];

(* creates a single cell *)
makeRegion[pts_] := Module[{n = (Range[#]~Partition~(#/2)) &@Length[pts], p, q, r},
p = Take[First[n], 2]~Join~Reverse@Take[Last[n], 2];
q = NestList[1 + # &, p, Length[First[n]] - 2];
r = Through[{First, Last}[First@n]]~Join~
Through[{Last, First}[Last@n]];
MeshRegion[pts, Polygon[Join[n, q, {r}]]]];


(* this creates the final lattice *)
q = Module[{p, origin = {0, 0, 0}, originend = {0, 1.9*6, 1.9}, 
 dispstart = {1.65, 0.95, 0}, dispend =  {-1.9, 1.9*5, 1.9}},
Reap[
 FoldList[Function[{pt, param},
   p = 
    Quiet@Table[
      Distribute[# + {{param[[1, 1]], i + param[[1, 2]], 
            param[[1, -1]]}}, List] & /@ pt,
      {i, param[[2, 1]], param[[2, 2]], param[[2, 3]]}];
   Sow[p]; First[p]], {pts1, pts2},
  {{origin, originend}, 
   Sequence @@ 
    Flatten[Array[{{dispstart, dispend}, {dispstart, 
         originend}} &, {2}], 1],
   {dispstart, dispend}}]]
][[2, 1]];
```

to create the final region (shown in the picture):

```
region = Region@*DiscretizeGraphics@Show[a = Flatten[
makeRegion/@ArrayReshape[#, Dimensions[#] /. {x_, y__, z_} :> {x, Times[y], z}] & /@ q]]
```

Now after creating the lattice i wish to create small particles (points) in the empty spaces between the cells. I create an artificial cylinder to first create arbitrary points and then use `RegionMember`to select the points.

[image]

```
pts = RandomPoint[Cylinder[{{4, 4, 0}, {4, 4, 1}}, 5], 1000];
Select[pts, ! RegionMember[region, #] &] // Length
(* 1000 *)
```

**However, I find that the same list of points are returned (nothing gets selected)**. Am i doing something wrong? How can i select the points that are not enveloped by the cells? Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your region is 2-dimensional, not 3-dimensional:

```
RegionDimension@region
```

> 2

*(you could also look at the output of RegionMember to see the embedding and region dimensions)*

So, only points on the surface of your cells belong to the region.

**Update**

Perhaps you could use [`DelaunayMesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DelaunayMesh) instead? Something like:

```
region = RegionUnion @@ Flatten[
    DelaunayMesh /@ ArrayReshape[#, Dimensions[#] /. {x_,y__,z_} :> {x,Times[y],z}]& /@ q
]

rmQ = RegionMember[region]
```

[image]

Then:

```
pts = RandomPoint[Cylinder[{{4,4,0},{4,4,1}}, 5], 1000];
Select[pts, Not @* rmQ] //Length
```

> 193

Note that using [`Pick`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick) instead of [`Select`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select) is faster:

```
Select[pts, Not @* rmQ] //Length //AbsoluteTiming
Pick[pts, rmQ[pts], False] //Length //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.003719, 193}
>
> {0.001406, 193}

Comment: thanks but i am specifying the third dimensions of the points with either a 0 or a 1. I am confused as to why region is not three dimensional in the end?

Comment: i see you mean the `RegionDimension` is 2 and should have been three. Is it possible to convert a surface to solid conveniently?

Comment: @AliHashmi The embedding dimension is 3. It's like the difference between Sphere[] and Ball[]. The first has dimension 2 (it is just the surface), even though it lives in 3 dimensions, while the second has dimension 3.

Comment: thanks figured it out. any convenient way to construct solids from closed surfaces? or is there any other way to select points external to the surfaces?

Comment: your proposed answer seems to be giving error message. I am using version 11.1.

Comment: in short `RegionUnion` is not giving me the union of all the mesh

Comment: @AliHashmi Looks like something to look forward to when you upgrade to 11.2!

Comment: oh what. 11.2 is out ?? !!

Comment: Not yet, but soon.

Comment: thanks i accepted the answer. Until i upgrade to version 11.2 i am using my version of the answer

Answer (score 1):

**Solution below should work for version 11.1.1 and earlier**

As @Carl Woll showed in his answer that the embedding dimension for `region` in question was 2 and not 3, so i replaced `MeshRegion` with `BoundaryMeshRegion` in `makeRegion` to provide an embedding dimension of 3.

```
makeRegion[pts_] := 
Module[{n = (Range[#]~Partition~(#/2)) &@Length[pts], p, q, r},
p = Take[First[n], 2]~Join~Reverse@Take[Last[n], 2];
q = NestList[1 + # &, p, Length[First[n]] - 2];
r = Through[{First, Last}[First@n]]~Join~
Through[{Last, First}[Last@n]];
BoundaryMeshRegion[pts, Polygon[Join[n, q, {r}]]]
]
```

then i can use:

```
pts = RandomPoint[Cylinder[{{4, 4, 0}, {4, 4, 1}}, 5], 1000];
fpts = Pick[pts, And @@@ Transpose[Function[x, ! RegionMember[x, #] & /@ pts] /@ a],True];

Show[region, Graphics3D[{Red, Point@fpts}]]
```

[image]